# Alias usage in ES6 'import'?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, node-modules, classloader, es6-modules

This is one form from many others for `import` [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

```js
var promise = import("module-name");
```

but my question is about this form of the statement. This `import` can be used both in browsers and in nodejs apps.

Does `module-name` always one of:

- URL (browsers apps)
- path in filesystem (nodejs apps)
- npm module name (nodejs apps)

Can we setup JS module loader to use aliases? For example, set mapping of aliases to URLs or to paths then import modules using aliases:

```js
import.mapping({
    "utils": "http://server.com/js/lib/utils.js"
});
```

or

```js
import.mapping({
    "utils": "/home/project/js/lib/utils.js"
});
```

then:

```js
import("utils").then(mod=>{...});
```

Comment: Check out [dynamic imports](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports).

Comment: Also a point is to allow library authors to write expressions like `import foo from 'foo';` and to deside where to download the `foo` script from by yourself. This is what require.js provides and what is missing in the browser module system to replace require.js completely. [Skypack](https://www.skypack.dev) tries to solve it by replacing the package names in `import from` expressions of libraries with the script URLs on the go.